# Express X-Powered-By still on css files

Tags: express, request-headers, express-handlebars, helmet.js

I am using helmet: `app.use(helmet())` and also tried adding `app.disable('x-powered-by')` for good measure to remove X-Powered-By headers.

The header is in fact removed on the html page that is generated but for files served from public using `app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');`it seems like the header is still showing up there. Is this normal behaviour? Is there a way to get rid of the header on those public files also?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into the same issue. I found out that this was just due to the caching of css files on the browser... Simply opening and closing the browser seemed to have the X-POWERED-BY header being stripped out now.